# Why the instrunmens show unavailable when I view the source?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I use the instruments to test if my app has some leaks.But when it shows a leak ,I enter the calltree. It shows unavailable.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

build setting ,change the debug information format to DWARF  with dSYM file